# Matching strings with grep and \A regexp

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Given the string in some file:

```
hel           string1
hell          string2
hello         string3
```

I'd like to capture just `hel` using `cat file | grep 'regexp here'`

I tried doing a bunch of regexp but none seem to work. What makes the most sense is: `grep -E '\Ahel'` but that doesn't seem to work. It works on `http://rubular.com/` however. Any ideas why that isn't working with `grep`?

Also, when pasting the above string with a tab space before each line, the `\A` does not seem to work on `rubular`. I thought `\A` matches beginning of string, and that doesn't matter whatever characters was before that. Why did `\A` stop matching when there was a space before the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERE doesn't support `\A` but PCRE does hence `grep -P` can be used with same regex (if available):

```
grep -P '\Ahel\b' file
hel           string1
```

Also important is to use word boundary `\b` to restrict matching `hello`

Alternatively in ERE you can use:

```
egrep '^hel\b' 
hel           string1
```

Comment: Seems like `-P` is not working for me. Here is what I did: `grep -E '^hel\b'` and that works. Why does `\b` work but `$` or `\z` doesn't?

Comment: `\b` is for word boundary. In your case `$` won't work since that means end of line and lines are not ending right after `hel`. Same goes for `\z` (ERE doesn't support it though)

Answer (score 3):

[ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html) (`-E`) does not support `\A` for indicating start of match.  Try `^` instead.

Use `-m 1` to stop grepping after the first match in each file.

If you want grep to print only the matched string (not the entire line), use `-o`.

Use `-h` if you want to suppress the printing of filenames in the grep output.

Example:

```
 grep -Eohm 1 "^hel" *.log
```

If you need to enforce only outputting if the search string is on the first line of the file, you could use `head`:

```
 head -qn 1 *.log | grep -Eoh "^hel"
```

Comment: `-m 1` will stop grep after the first match in each file.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought \A matches beginning of string, and that doesn't matter whatever characters was before that. Why did \A stop matching when there was a space before the string?

`\A` matches the very beginning of the text, it doesn't match the start-of-line when you have one or more lines in your text.

Anyway, grep doesn't support `\A` so you need to use `^` which by the way matches the start of each line in multi-line mode contrary to `\A`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '$1=="hel"' file
```

PS you do not need to cat file to grep, use `grep 'regexp here' file`